# Is it possible to cancel a job in the printer spooler with cancel -a

Tags: printing, remote, cups

I need to cancel a printing job in a printer cause the job I want to send is a "high priority" job. I have CentOS 6.2 installed.
I know that with CUPS and `cancel -a` I can cancel all local printer jobs BUT :

1. Does the spooler cancelling is limited to the local spooler (the computer) or can I cancel all jobs even those coming from other computers?
2. Does it do the same if the printer is linked by usb or by the network?